# Prove that $\bigcap{x} = \left\{z: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x \right\}$ is a set, where $x \neq \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Here is the proposition to be proved:

> Let $x$ be a non-empty set. Show that the intersection of $x$, written as $\bigcap{x}$, defined informally by
> \begin{equation*}
> \bigcap{x} = \left\{z: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\},
> \end{equation*}
> is a set in ZF.

Below is my argument.

Assume that $x \neq \emptyset$. According to the Axiom of Union, the following class
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup{x} = \left\{z: \textrm{there exists a set $y \in x$ such that $z \in y$}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
is a set in ZF. Then the class $\left\{z \in \bigcup{x}: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\}$
is a set according to the Axiom of Separation. Further, assume that
\begin{equation*}
z \in \bigcap{x} = \left\{z: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
As $z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x$ and $x \neq \emptyset$, then there must exist a $y_{0} \in x$ such that $z \in y_{0}$. Then
\begin{equation*}
z \in \bigcup{x},
\end{equation*}
and we may conclude
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap{x} \subseteq \bigcup{x}.
\end{equation*}
The following class
\begin{equation*}
\left\{z \in \bigcup{x}: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\}
\end{equation*}
has to be a set according to the Axiom of Separation, and
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap{x} = \left\{z: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\} = \left\{z \in \bigcup{x}: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap{x} = \left\{z: z \in y \textrm{ for all } y \in x\right\},
\end{equation*}
is indeed a set.

P.S. I found that proofs of theorems in set theory are constructed informally, although the axioms are written formally. The type of sayings like "$\left\{x:\phi\left(x\right)\right\}$ is a set" is not a very formal expression, but we accept a lot of such sayings in proofs. Also, "$=$" should be used in formal deductions. I am not very sure if this symbol can be used in arbitrary situations like "$\left\{z: \phi\left(z\right)\right\} = s$". As if $\left\{z: \phi\left(z\right)\right\}$ is not a set, then the class cannot be talked about in a formal system, then this "$=$" is not the same "$=$" which is introduced as a predicate of the formal language.

Comment: Your proof is fine.